# tkinter photoimage get image from another file

Tags: python, image, tkinter, directory

In my program, there any many images that are placed in a tkinter window, and i'm using the following code to place one image:

```
imgCapa = tk.PhotoImage(file='capa.png')
self.canvasTitulo.create_image(800,300,
                               image=imgCapa,
                                anchor='se')
```

The problem is that there are many images and i would like to place all of them inside a folder instead of placing inside the same folder of the python code, and read them from there.

Answer (score 0):

just make a folder and add you path to `file`

```
imgCapa1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='my_folder/capa1.png')
imgCapa2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='my_folder/capa2.png')
self.canvasTitulo.create_image(800,300,
                           image=imgCapa1,
                            anchor='se')
```